# Plot the average values for each level

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, mean

Using ggplot2 generate a plot which shows the following data.

```
df=data.frame(score=c(4,2,3,5,7,6,5,6,4,2,3,5,4,8),
              age=c(18,18,23,50,19,39,19,23,22,22,40,35,22,16))
str(df)
df
```

Instead of doing a frequency plot of the variables (see below code), I want to generate a plot of the average values for each x value. So I want to plot the average score at each age level. At age 18 on the x axis, we might have a **3** on the y axis for score. At age 23, we might have an average score of **4.5**, and so forth (**Edit**: average values corrected). This would ideally be represented with a barplot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(age), y=factor(score))) + geom_bar()
```

> Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

Just not sure how to do this in R with ggplot2 and can't seem to find anything on such plots. Statistically, I don't know if the plot I desire to plot is even the right thing to do, but that's a different store.

Comment: Did you want average values, because from your dataset average values at 18 age is 3 (not 3.5), and at 23 age - 4.5 (not 6.2)?

Comment: Yeah, I want averages. In that example, I just made up some numbers w/o thinking about it.

Comment: @ATMathew, but since you're going making the effort of providing some sample data, you should also make sure that your sample output is accurate for the provided data. Otherwise, it leads to unnecessary confusion....

Comment: Just as a comment, in case that you have different groups, like gender, and you want a plot with the group mean on it, `aes(x=factor(age), y=score, group = gender, color = gender))`, `group` separate the sample `color` just give them different colors and a legend

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use summary functions in `ggplot`. Here are two ways of achieving the same result:

```
# Option 1
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(age), y = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean")

# Option 2
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(age), y = score)) + 
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar")
```

[image]

Older versions of `ggplot` use `fun.y` instead of `fun`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(age), y = score)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar")
```

Comment: Add a note about how the OP probably didn't want to convert the scores to a factor and you'll have my answer exactly.

Comment: @DrDom, the answer is so obvious now that you've posted it! (+1)

Comment: @joran, yes, I've considered that in my answer. Since mean of factors will be meaningless value in this case. :)

Comment: Hello, how can you add the mean as labels for each bar?

Answer (score 8):

If I understood you right, you could try something like this:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ddply(df, .(age), mean), aes(x=factor(age), y=factor(score))) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: what does the ".(age)" mean/do? Is that a base R thing or ggplot (/tidyverse?) specific?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `aggregate()` in base R instead of loading another package.

```
temp = aggregate(list(score = df$score), list(age = factor(df$age)), mean)
ggplot(temp, aes(x = age, y = score)) + geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is doing a `group_by` of the x-values and `summarise` the "mean_score" per "age" using `dplyr` to do it in one pipe. Also you can use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
df=data.frame(score=c(4,2,3,5,7,6,5,6,4,2,3,5,4,8),
              age=c(18,18,23,50,19,39,19,23,22,22,40,35,22,16))
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  group_by(age) %>%
  summarise(mean_score = mean(score)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(age), y = mean_score)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "Mean score")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>