# ggplot2 : Plot mean with geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization

I have the following data frame:

```
test2 <- data.frame(groups = c(rep("group1",4), rep("group2",4)), 
    X2 = c(rnorm(4), rnorm(4)) , 
    label = c(rep(1,2),rep(2,2),rep(1,2),rep(2,2)))
```

and I am plotting the bar graphs for each label per group using:

```
ggplot(test2, aes(label, X2, fill=as.factor(groups))) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

However, I am cannot seem to be able to find a `stat="mean"` so I can plot the means on each bar graph instead of the identity.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This tutorial provides a good description of how to achieve this: http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-barplot-with-ggplot2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting the average values for each level in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857935/plotting-the-average-values-for-each-level-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

simply use `stat = "summary"` and `fun.y = "mean"`

```
ggplot(test2) + 
  geom_bar(aes(label, X2, fill = as.factor(groups)), 
           position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is awesome and really elegant. Thanks! Do you happen to know how to get darker colors in a nice way?

Comment: How do you modify this, to add labels on top of the bars?

Comment: Tried this with `ggplot 3.3.2` and it seems like `fun.y` has been deprecated. Use `fun = "mean"` instead.

Comment: Is this solution also compatible with geom_errorbar?

Answer (score 6):

`ggplot2` likes 1 data point for  1 plot point. Create a new data frame with your summary statistics, then plot with `stat="identity"`

```
require(reshape2)
plot.data <- melt(tapply(test2$X2, test2$groups,mean), varnames="group", value.name="mean")

 ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=group,y=mean)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ggpubr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpubr/index.html). It creates ggplot2-like charts.

```
library(ggpubr)

ggbarplot(test2, x = "label", y = "X2",
          add = "mean", fill = "groups")
```

[image]

Alternatively, add a facet:

```
ggbarplot(test2, x = "label", y = "X2",
          add = "mean", fill = "groups",
          facet.by = "groups")
```

[image]